# It seems Xubuntu does ´touch´ a microsd card in a way that is recognizable by retropie for instance - what does it do?

Tags: permissions, dd, read-only

if i for instance insert one of my Retropie
microsd cards in my other desktop pc
which runs Xubuntu 18.04 LTS, if i do not
lock the microsd card with the switch in
the SDHC-microsd card adaptor, Xubuntu ´seems´
to do something to the card, in a way that when
i put it back in my Raspberry Pi, the Raspberry
starts searching folders and other stuff before
the initial boot of emulation station.
This is a significant symptom i get when
i have inserted any microsd card in an other
pc or device, when it was not set to be
Read-Only. I run Linux Xubuntu 18.04 LTS on
all my systems btw. But what does it do
with a microsd card which is not Read-Only,
and i did not do ANY fileoperation (copying/
deleting whatever) on this card, I only
made an Disk (.IMG) with Disks of it.
Can anyone tell me what Xubuntu ´does´
to a microsd card inserted in this way. ?
It does not corrupt anything but i should
assume if i do nothing like copying to it,
or deleting from it, there should be ZERO
traceable actions of this microsdcard having
been inserted in an other computer ... ?

Comment: I doubt Xubuntu does anything, but I'll offer this as a something possibly worth chasing down. `thunar` (XFCE's File Manager) will scan directories and create thumbnails (if the option is not disabled) so when displays; it can quickly display them.  Maybe you have thumbnail cache turned on & thus it's trying to pre-create the thumbnails of images; but I have no experience of this being a problem with pi though I recall it may have left a [hidden] file in the directory it scanned.  Maybe `gnome-disks` mounts the sdcard for its image, or my '*thought*' is completely wrong..

Comment: you might be right the card is normally always mounted first when i insert it for making a disk .img image with disks from it. i then manually unmount it or skip that part and let gnomedisks unmount it (i think it unmounts automatically when starting to make a image from the card).